# Determine $f_{0}$ and $a(t)$ with help of trigonometric identity

Tags: calculus

-The aditive superposition of two sinusoidal oscillations of equal amplitude but slightly different frequencies:

$ s_{1}(t)=s_{a}cos(2\pi f_{1}t )  $

$ s_{2}(t)=s_{a}cos(2\pi (f_{1}+\Delta f)t ) $

-Represent a sinusoidal oscillations with relatively slowly varying amplitude in form:

$s(t)=a(t)cos(2\pi f_{0}t )  $  with help of $2cos\alpha cos\beta =cos(\alpha -\beta )+cos(\alpha +\beta )$

Determine $f_{0}$ and $a(t)$.

I have silimiar example solved and I try on the same way this but cant finish.

**What I did:**

$s(t)=s_{1}(t)+s_{2}(t)$

$ s(t)=s_{a}(cos(2\pi f_{1}t )+cos(2\pi (f_{1}+\Delta f)t)  $

$\alpha +\beta =2\pi f_{1}t$

$\alpha -\beta =2\pi t(f_{1} + \Delta f )$

And from these two equations I got little bit more complicated alpha and beta. At the end I used $2cos\alpha cos\beta =cos(\alpha -\beta )+cos(\alpha +\beta )$

and finally got this:

$s(t)=s_{a}2cos(\pi t(f_{1}+tf_{1}+t \Delta f ))cos(\pi t(f_{1}t-f_{1}-t \Delta f)) $  But I cant get from this $f_{0}$ and $a(t)$. Can anyone help me with this?

Edit: $s_{a}$ is amplitude but I didnt know how to do it in Latex.

Comment: The third last line should be $s(t)=s_a 2cos(πt(f1+f1+Δf))cos(πt(f1−f1−Δf)) $since you have taken the $t$ common.

Comment: But still how to get f0 and a from it?

Comment: Simplifying $s(t)=2s_a cos(2\pi t(f1+\Delta f /2))cos(\pi \Delta f t)$ .Therefore, $f_0 = f1 +\Delta f /2$ and $a(t)=2s_a cos(\pi \Delta f t)$.I personally think that we can take $cos(\pi \Delta f t)=1$ since $\Delta f$ is approximately zero.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!